# concrete5.7 Help extending MiniSurvey Class

Tags: class, extend, concrete5, concrete5-5.7

Since moving to 5.7 I no longer know how to extend classes.

I'm building a custom form and need to extend the MiniSurvey Class (concrete/blocks/form/mini_survey.php) so I can make one small change to the loadInputType function.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Show us your attempts,your trials and we'll be glad to help you!

Comment: There's a good howTo here: https://www.concrete5.org/documentation/how-tos/developers/override-almost-any-core-file-in-5.7/

Comment: Thanks for your replies, all.  Sorry I didn't reply sooner, I never received an email alert to your replies.

I've got it to work now, I copied mini_survey.php into applications/blocks/form/ and updated the namespace to namespace Application\Block\Form;

In previous version of C5, I've been use to extending a class where you could add a new function or update an existing one.  In the latest version it looks like you have to override the entire class.

I've got it working now, but thanks for your replies.

Comment: @JonathanCarey sorry for the late answer too! You should add your answer your question, and accept it yourself - http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer